# Recortar una imagen Bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

Tengo una imagen `Bitmap mapa` con una imagen precargada, lo que quiero hacer es recortar esa imagen y generar otro Bitmap con ese recorte.

El recorte es dinámico, por lo cual tengo las coordenadas `(x,y)` de inicio así como la `anchura` y `altura` para saber sus dimensiones.

```
Rectangle rectOrig = new Rectangle(posXmin, posYmin, anchura, altura);

Bitmap mapa = new Bitmap(anchura, altura, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

Hasta ahorita tengo `rectOrig` con el rectángulo que deseo obtener, pero de ahí no sé qué hacer para guardar ese rectángulo en un Bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias implementar algo como ser

```
Bitmap source = new Bitmap(@"C:\imagen1.jpg");
Rectangle rectOrig = new Rectangle(posXmin, posYmin, anchura, altura);

Bitmap CroppedImage = CropImage(source, rectOrig);
```

Entonces cortas usando

```
public Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap source, Rectangle section)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    return bmp;
}
```

La idea es usar `GDI` para aplicar el `Rectangle` a la imagen

Fuente: 
[How to cut a part of image in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484935/how-to-cut-a-part-of-image-in-c-sharp)

Comment: ¿El uso de Graphics  g es para mostrar la imagen recortada? Mi aplicacion es una aplicacion de consola por lo que no tengo un form

Comment: pero no necesita ser un form, solo agrega el using a System.Drawing